# pseudocode - whats wrong?

Tags: math-mode

Its driving me crazy now!!! I want it as shown in image. But getting error!  Whats wrong here:

```
\begin{equation} \label{eq4}
    \textbf{Y} = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
                   YES & \text{  if  \sum\sum(\textbf{Y} \circ \textbf{G}) > \tfrac{r^{2}}{2} } \\
                   NO  & \text{otherwise}
                        \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\text` command places its content in text mode, while you have math-only content within it (`\sum`,`\tfrac`, etc.). Use `\text{YES} & \text{ if } \sum\sum(\mathbf{Y} \circ \mathbf{G}) > \tfrac{r^{2}}{2}`

I would also recommend `cases` from `amsmath` instead of `array`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

With \texttt{array}:
\begin{equation} \label{eq4}
    \textbf{Y} = \left\{\begin{array}{cl}
                   \text{YES} & \text{if } \sum\sum(\mathbf{Y} \circ \mathbf{G}) > \tfrac{r^{2}}{2}  \\
                   \text{NO} & \text{otherwise}
                        \end{array}\right.
\end{equation}


With \texttt{cases}:
\begin{equation} \label{eq5}
    \textbf{Y} = \begin{cases}
                   \text{YES} & \text{if } \sum\sum(\mathbf{Y} \circ \mathbf{G}) > \tfrac{r^{2}}{2}  \\
                   \text{NO} & \text{otherwise}
                        \end{cases}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thanks for the explanation as well :)